# How to get the timestamp from this string / laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

This text is saved all in one column in database table. I want to take the time-stamp from the chat replies. Is there any command who can split the string and get the time-stamp.
The chat starts from here:____________________________________________________________________________

Hi Guest 4878,

Thank you for chatting with us. Please find your chat transcript below.

### Date: 2017-02-07

Name: Guest 4878
Email: 
Topic:

### Chat reference number: 11701

| 07.02.2017 13:46:36 | Guest 4878: Anybody here?

| 07.02.2017 13:46:52 | Admin: Hello, how may I help you?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Carbon` For that:

```
\Carbon\Carbon::parse($yourTimestamp)->format('H:i:s');
```

Or like this:

```
\Carbon\Carbon::parse($yourTimestamp)->timestamp;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$time = \Carbon\Carbon:::createFromFormat('d.m.Y H:i:s', '07.02.2017 13:46:36');

//Or using model
$time = \Carbon\Carbon:::createFromFormat('d-m-Y H:i:s', $model->datetime);

//display timestamp
echo $time->timestamp;
```